# iPhone SDK - Where did I finish touching the screen?

Tags: iphone, sdk

Is there any way for the touchesEnded method to tell me the position of where I lifted my finger?
Also, can it tell me which finger was lifted if I had 2 (or more) on the device? (e.g. if I put finger 1 down, then finger 2 down, then lifted finger 2 but held down finger 1, could it tell me that I have ended finger 2?)

Thanks
Jon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at [the touch methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html) that are inherited by UIViews, specifically `touchesEnded:withEvent:` will tell you when / where the touches ended (i.e. where you lifted your finger).

Just override these methods in your view controller like this and you can find out where the touch refers to :

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    // Get a touch
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    // Where did it end?
    CGPoint endedAt = [touch locationInView:[self view]];
    ...
```

The touch object will be the same (`isEqual:`) to the touch that was sent in the `touchesBegan:withEvent:` method. This should let you track multiple touches if you store the touches that you are interested in in your touchesBegan and compare them in your touchesEnded